# Metro theme for phpmyadmin not working

Tags: 14.04, phpmyadmin

I have installed metro theme for phpmyadmin on ubuntu system. While the same file displying perfectly on a windows system but fails to load style on ubuntu system.

[image]

Is there anything that i am missing during installation or adding new theme ?

Currently using Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: same here - any luck getting this sorted out ? - seems like some of the pmahomme styles are persisting

Comment: I also am having this issue

Comment: I also installed the same. But my trouble is it's rendering. It is super cool in firefox and the same totally stinks in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading the theme from here: http://hplhu.deviantart.com/art/Metro-Theme-v3-for-phpMyAdmin-4-382030120.
This one works perfect for me.
Steps (As on ubuntu):

1. Download
2. Extract
3. move the extracted folder to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes`
4. Open `phpmyadmin` from web browser
5. select the Metro theme from options

Done! Simple and easy.

Comment: No, it's same as earlier. Which version of ubuntu and phpmyadmin are you using ??

Comment: Yes, now I got the problem. Need to change the permission of that folder to 0777. Installation was perfect from the beginning. Permission issue was there.

Answer (score 0):

Download the theme from [files.phpmyadmin.net](https://files.phpmyadmin.net/themes/metro/2.4/metro-2.4.zip), unzip and paste in the folder where `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes` is installed
.